# How to retrive all the nodes of a root node using php and my sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a structure like this:

- `A`(Root Node) have two child `B`(left child) and `C`(right child).
- Similarly `B` has also two node `D`(left child) and `E`(right child).
- Similarly `C` has also two node `F`(left child), `G`(right child) like so one.

My query is that:

- If I input `A`(root node) the it will show all  the child nodes which is under `A`, the out put is like this `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, `G`,
- similarly if I input `B` then the the out put will be like this `D`, `E`.

My second query is that If I input `A` then it will show which is his left child as well as right child.

My Table structure is like this

```
id     c_n      p_n 

1       B        A

2       C        A

3       D        B

4       E        B
```

like so on.

Here there are three fields one is `id`, `c_n`, `p_n`.

Can any body help me?

Answer (score 0):

Given your current schema, the following will pull child nodes from 1 or 2 levels of heirarchy (conditionally) in a comma delimited string, per your request

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        GROUP_CONCAT(t1.c_n), 
        IF(COUNT(t2.c_n), ',', ''), 
        GROUP_CONCAT(t2.c_n)
    ) AS nodex
FROM table_name AS t1
LEFT JOIN table_name AS t2 ON t1.c_n = t2.p_n
WHERE t1.p_n = 'A'
GROUP BY t1.p_n
```

However, you should consider switching to a `nested set` model for simplicity and speed of selects.

Answer (score 0):

You should introduce two additional fields, `lft` and `rgt`, and use the nested tree model for your table that makes use of these two columns.

An example document explaining this setup and use is [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

This will allow you to make these sorts of queries much more efficiently.

For instance, to get the whole tree then, you just have to query for all nodes who's `lft` is greater than the roots, and who's `rgt` is smaller.